# When to use add_action vs add_filter?

Tags: wordpress

It seems cleaner to make a plugin and use add_action -- why would you use add_filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_filter` hook is mainly used to change the content before displaying it ..

Suppose I want to print the title as bold when I use `the_title()` function of WordPress. So to modify this function only in terms of display, we can use `add_filters`.

Example : `add_filter( 'the_title', function( $title ) { return '<b>' . $title . '</b>'; } );`